# Uninstall Excel from a dead computer

Tags: microsoft-excel

Can I uninstall Excel 2010 from a computer if the motherboard is damaged and I can no longer turn the computer on?

Comment: No, why do you care to uninstall if the computer dosent work at all?

Comment: I have purchased another computer and wish to install Excel on it

Comment: Simply uninstalling Excel from the computer that no longer works isn't a guarantee that you have the rights to install that license on another computer.  You would have to read the license for the version of Excel you have a license in order to determine if you have the right to install it on another machine.

Comment: Similarly, if you try to activate and run into a problem you can call MS and explain - they have the ability to add activations onto license keys.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can!

Take a look: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/officeversion_other-word/tranfering-word-and-excel-to-my-new-computer/33db0a7e-e55f-4eb5-86e7-8a16d3dfdd10

> Reinstall from the original install disc on your new computer and
>   proceed to reactivate by telephone if required:
>
> Microsoft Office Activation Number:
>   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/950929

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft will likely not care if you install it on another computer, if you've replaced it. If you're really worried about it read your licensing, or you can call to activate your license and they'll tell you whether or not they care.

Like I said though, they likely will not care at all. One license isn't something they worry terribly about, plus business licenses swap around computers all the time. As long as you aren't going to use your old computer anymore they wont care.

I've had this experience with office 2010 moving from one computer to another, as well as Windows XP and Windows 7 operating systems.

This is a bit off topic, but you should destroy your old hard drive unless you plan on using it again, or at least research and use a DoD drive wiping utility. Data is extremely easy to recover data from hard drives even if you format them. The link below shows some basic info about it.

http://lifehacker.com/5951822/how-can-i-recover-data-from-a-dead-or-erased-hard-drive